# List of Project Plan Templates in PWA

Tags: project-server, project-online, pwa

I have created a bunch of Project Templates and would like to get rid of some that I don't need, or write over some that I need to change.

When I open up Project professional and connect to my account on my PWA, I can click open and connect to my PWA and I see a list of all my projects on PWA, great. Now I change to Project Templates, but the list doesn't then change, and I still don't see the list of existing templates.
The only place I can seem to find the list of templates is by going into *PWA* > *Server Settings* > *Enterprise Project Types* > Choosing an existing *Project Type* and then clicking the drop down for *Project Plan Template*.

How do I delete existing Project Plan Templates?

Answer (score 1):

A template can be deleted the same way a project can:

- Go to PWA settings
- In the Queue and Database Administration group, click Delete Enterprise Objects
- Select the template you want to delete from the list
- Click delete button (at the top of the page)

Hope this helps!